# How do I use TypeScript typing information from a Node.js package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import, package

I've read a ton of different variations of this same question, but I just can't wrap my mind around it. I'm using the `websocket` module (which I've used many times before without TypeScript) and I can't figure out how to type my variables?

I have a function that takes in a `WebSocketConnection` object, but when I give it the type `WebSocketConnection` I get a `"Cannot find name 'WebSocketConnection'"` from TypeScript.

I've installed the `@types/websocket` package and I can see the `index.d.ts` file with all the type definitions in it located in `./node_modules/@types/websocket/index.d.ts` relative to my `tsconfig.json` file...

I've tried adding the `"typeRoots"` option to the `tsconfig.json` file, as well as `"types"`. I've tried many combination of values but as far as I can tell leaving them off entirely is a better bet, so I've tried that as well. I've also tried many variations of `import`ing data from both the `.d.ts` file and also the package itself, with no luck of course.

I tried using `/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/websocket/index.d.ts" />` also with no luck.

I looked in the `.d.ts` file and found a very clear declaration of an interface called `IStringified` that looked like this:

```
export interface IStringified {
    toString: (...args: any[]) => string;
}
```

So I tried to access `IStringified` and I'm still getting the same `"Cannot find name 'IStringified'"` error.

I'm probably just being really dumb and missing something plainly obvious, but any pointers or advice would be much appreciated! What in the world am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types of installed packages are not available globally. They must be imported into each file in order to use them. Don't mess with `typeroots` or triple slash directives at all, that will only make things worse.

In this particular case, [the module exports a `connection` class](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/websocket/index.d.ts#L356), which is probably what you want. It's unfortunate name means to make it it look the class constructor that it really is you should probably rename in on import:

```
import {
  server as WebSocketServer,
  connection as WebSocketConnection,
} from 'websocket'
```

And now you can do:

```
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({ httpServer: server });

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
  var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
  doSomethingWithWsConnection(connection) // works
});

function doSomethingWithWsConnection(connection: WebSocketConnection) {
  //...
}
```

[Typesafe example on TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2&ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#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)

---

> So I tried to access IStringified and I'm still getting the same "Cannot find name 'IStringified'" error.

You import the type, then use the type:

```
import { IStringified } from 'websocket'
const foo: IStringified = { toString: () => 'asdf' }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgSQMoysAdgc2AM2AFMATOAXznyghDgHIB3IgIwGcIBjAayJnoBQnCFjbx8ECAC4U6TLgLEyAXkRwYEOdhwyAFAEo4ygHwMAhmxL56FIA)

Comment: To expand on this, `export { IStringified } from 'websockets'` works fine in @AlexWayne's playground example